# SyntaxError: invalid syntax for no reason at all?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I Dont understand the issue, I believe that the main issue is that the bracket from line "if ("
is not closed. But wherever i try to close it. i still get an issue!

```
    if(
    self.proxy_address and int(self.proxy_port > 0) or \
     Settings.connection_type = "proxy" 
     self.aborting = False
    self.start_time = time.time()
    self.proxy_chrome_extension:
    # assign logger
    self.show_logs = show_logs
    Settings.show_logs = show_logs or None
    self.multi_logs = multi_logs
    self.logfolder = get_logfolder(self.username, self.multi_logs)
    self.logger = self.get_instapy_logger(self.show_logs)
```

this is my error log

```
 File "c:\Users\refaa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 272, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\refaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\refaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\refaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\refaa\Desktop\instapy-quickstart-master\instapy-quickstart-master\quickstart.py", line 19, in <module>
    from instapy import InstaPy
  File "C:\Users\refaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\instapy\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .instapy import InstaPy
  File "C:\Users\refaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 279
    Settings.connection_type = "proxy"
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\Users\refaa\Desktop\instapy-quickstart-master\instapy-quickstart-master>
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error so it is easier.

Comment: @student there is about a syntax error per line...

Comment: I'd start with an IDE with syntax highlighting...

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? You have not defined your if condition correctly, also
`self.proxy_chrome_extension:` is not valid, is it an if condition or a variable assignment, I assumed variable assignment

```
if (self.proxy_address and int(self.proxy_port > 0) or Settings.connection_type == "proxy"):
    self.aborting = False
    self.start_time = time.time()
    self.proxy_chrome_extension = None
    # assign logger
    self.show_logs = show_logs
    Settings.show_logs = show_logs or None
    self.multi_logs = multi_logs
    self.logfolder = get_logfolder(self.username, self.multi_logs)
    self.logger = self.get_instapy_logger(self.show_logs)
```

For future purposes, consider using a IDE like PyCharm which does syntax highlighting for you

Comment: Hi OP, You need to provide if you get an error with my code you tried as a comment, and not an edit to the original answer

Comment: I changed it exactly to yours                if(self.proxy_address and int(self.proxy_port > 0) or Settings.connection_type == "proxy"): 
        self.aborting = False
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.proxy_chrome_extension = None
        # assign logger
        self.show_logs = show_logs
        Settings.show_logs = show_logs or None
        self.multi_logs = multi_logs
        self.logfolder = get_logfolder(self.username, self.multi_logs)
        self.logger = self.get_instapy_logger(self.show_logs)

Comment: it is wayy too big but this is as much as i can get it                                       Exception has occurred: IndentationError
expected an indented block (instapy.py, line 278)
  File "C:\Users\refaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\instapy\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .instapy import InstaPy
  File "C:\Users\refaa\Desktop\instapy-quickstart-master\instapy-quickstart-master\quickstart.py", line 19, in <module>
    from instapy import InstaPy
  File "C:\Users\refaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code

Comment: also you took out the "\" idk if you did that on purpose or not

Comment: The `\\` is for breaking the for loop in multiple lines which I remove for simplicity

Comment: Also self.proxy_chrome_extension: is a variable assignment or an if loop?

Comment: ok so the issue is that i didnt make this. what is happening is that i am coding for an instagram liking bot and when i make the bot. i click run and for some reason. It opens up a new coded tab called instapy.py which is like 7k lines long and its telling me the error code i have provided above. By the way i am using Visual studio code. Another thing is that i have fixed my older error. and now the new error is  TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' which is my older error i had yesterday and it seems no matter what i fix it always goes back to the same thing

Comment: also i am the one who coded my instagram bot. but i did NOT code the 7k line thing idk why that keeps coming up idk what to do!

Comment: then you need to dig deeper from where you picked the code up, and how your `instapy.py` is being generated